# Changing attribute values of an instance of a class at runtime

Tags: python

I'm creating a small game which relies on user selection to determine the stats of the character he/she wants. The game consists of "stats" which are determined by the players "race". I have run into issues as I need this action to be completed at run time. I am unsure of what I need to do to complete this and any help would be appreciated.

The implementation must be able to support future addition of run time determined factors such as "faction" and "gender". This is only a consideration and is not asking for implementation of this thus far.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, race, faction):
        self.playerName = name
        self.playerGender = gender
        self.playerRace = race
        self.playerFaction = faction
        self.setPlayerStats("","","","","")
#CHARACTER STATS
    def setPlayerStats(self, mining, manufacturing, exploration, invention, trading):
        self.mining = mining
        self.manufacturing = manufacturing
        self.exploration = exploration
        self.invention = invention
        self.trading = trading

    def playerStats(self):
        self.setPlayerStats(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
#CHARACTER CLASSES
class Dwarf(Character):
    def playerStats(self):
        self.setPlayerStats(3, 1, 0, 1, 0)

class Elf(Character):
    def playerStats(self):
        self.setPlayerStats(0, 1, 0, 1, 3

    def setPlayerRace(self):
        self.playerRace = "Elf"

class Human(Character):
    def playerStats(self):
        self.setPlayerStats(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    def setPlayerRace(self):
        self.playerRace = "Human"

class Orc(Character):
    def playerStats(self):
        self.setPlayerStats(0, 2, 2, 1, 0)

    def setPlayerRace(self):
        self.playerRace = "Orc"
```

The issue I am having with the current implementation method isn't actually setting these variables as it is not being set to the instance of the "character" class. I have been told this is a runtime issue and I am unfamiliar with how to do this in Python.

```
print("Please choose the numerical value assigned to the option you wish to select:")
        print("1) Dwarf 2) Elf 3) Human 4) Orc")
        userInput = input(str("Input your character`s race: "))
        if userInput == "1":
            player1 = Dwarf("","","","")
            break
        elif userInput == "2":
            player1 = Elf("","","","")
            break
        elif userInput == "3":
            player1 = Human("","","","")
            break
        elif userInput == "4":
            player1 = Orc("","","","")
            break
        else:
            input("Invaild Input! Press any button to try again...")
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: I want to know how to set the values of the character race which contain the values of the player stats at runtime. Currently, I cannot set the values linked to an instance of a character.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show some code that produces an unwanted output or error, show this output/error and the desired output or behavior?

Comment: Do you actually need to write different *code* to explain how humans/dwarves/elves work differently, or can you do it all through *data* as shown thus far? Consider not bothering with subclasses, at least until you've proven a need.

Comment: You should pass the race as an argument: `player1 = Dwarf("", "", "Dwarf", "")`

Comment: "Currently, I cannot set the values linked to an instance of a character." Okay, so what part of your code do you expect to do this?

Comment: `Dwarf` is missing the `setPlayerRace()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a right-parenthesis for `Elf(Character).playerStats`

```
class Elf(Character):
    def playerStats(self):
        self.setPlayerStats(0, 1, 0, 1, 3
```

Also, you had a lot of `break` statements which were not inside of a loop.

```
elif userInput == "2":
    player1 = Elf("","","","")
    break
```

The word "player" usually refers to the human sitting in front of the computer (or an AI, or something playing the game). The character controlled by the player is not the player. For example, the player often types on a keyboard, whereas, the "player-controlled-character" might swing a sword, or fire an arrow from a bow. In order to not confuse things I recommend you apply an `edit>replace` on the word "`player`." For one thing, the player needs a GUI (graphical user-interface), whereas, the player-controlled-character does not. You might want create a `player` class at some point in order to handle user-input. Alternatively, a single player might "own" several different characters. Puppets and puppeteers are different things.

Setting stats is easy:

```
Create a character
character = Orc("Mr. Orc", "male", "Orc", "zebra faction")
# Below, set the stats at runtime 
character.mining = 455
print(character.mining)
character.setPlayerStats(self, mining=1, manufacturing=2, exploration=3, invention=4, trading=5)
```

If you want to set stats for an entire race, you could write something like:

```
class Race:
    def __init__(self, mining, manufacturing, exploration, invention, trading):
        self.mining = mining
        self.manufacturing = manufacturing
        self.exploration = exploration
        self.invention = invention
        self.trading = trading

Dwarf = Race(3, 1, 0, 1, 0)

class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, race:Race, faction):
        self.playerName = name
        self.playerGender = gender
        self.playerRace = race
        self.playerFaction = faction
#CHARACTER STATS
    def getTotalStats(self):
        return (
            self.race.mining + self.mining_bonus,
            self.race.manufacturing + self.manufacturing_bonus,
            self.race.exploration + self.exploration,
            self.race.invention + self.invention,
            self.race.trading + self.trading,
        )
```